# Saving a powerpoint file using C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I just need to create a `.pptx` file with 1 dummy slide using C# and save it to the current directory. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

So far, I have this code to create a Powerpoint presentation:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application obj = new Application();
obj.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
```

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet creates a new presentation:

```
    private void DpStartPowerPoint()
{
    // Create the reference variables
    PowerPoint.Application ppApplication = null;
    PowerPoint.Presentations ppPresentations = null;
    PowerPoint.Presentation ppPresentation = null;

    // Instantiate the PowerPoint application
    ppApplication = new PowerPoint.Application();

    // Create a presentation collection holder
    ppPresentations = ppApplication.Presentations;

    // Create an actual (blank) presentation
    ppPresentation = ppPresentations.Add(Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

    // Activate the PowerPoint application
    ppApplication.Activate();
}
```

And this code snippet saves it:

```
    // Assign a filename under which to save the presentation
string myFileName = "myPresentation";

// Save the presentation unconditionally
ppPresentation.Save();

// Save the presentation as a PPTX
ppPresentation.SaveAs(myFileName,
                      PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsDefault, 
                      Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

// Save the presentation as a PDF
ppPresentation.SaveAs(myFileName,
                      PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPDF, 
                      Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

// Save a copy of the presentation
ppPresentation.SaveCopyAs(“Copy of “ + myFileName,
                          PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsDefault, 
                          Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue);
```

See [this page](http://www.davidallenpollock.com/AutomatingPowerPoint.html) for references on other powerpoint automation capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

The following resources include how to save file and also many other code samples on how to manipulate `Ms - Power Point` presentation files using `C#`:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomatePowerPoint-b312d416

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10068596/create-ppt-slides-through-cnet.aspx

Hope this helps

**Edit:**

The following includes details about adding references:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303718

Comment: Hi, is there another way to do this instead of using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application obj = new Application(); as that is throwing an exception for me.

Comment: What is the exception being thrown?

Comment: Do you need to have powerpoint installed on your computer for this to work

Comment: [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException] = {"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {91493441-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))."}

Answer (score 0):

Create such a file using PowerPoint, and embed it as a resource in your C# application. Then copy it to a file whenever you need to.