# Change text only temporarily

Tags: c#, powerpoint, shapes

I want to change the text of a Powerpoint shape only during presentation (i.e. while the slide is shown), but not change the text permanently so that it modifies the PPT file.

Currenty I'm subscribing to the event

```
Application.SlideShowNextSlide += OnNextSlide;
```

and then I change the text on one specific shape like this:

```
shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Hello world";
```

However, when the presentation ends, that text is in the PPT file and Powerpoint asks me whether I want to save the changes.

I want to avoid that my Powerpoint Add-In makes changes to the file.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
Based on Steve's answer and your feedback in the comments. So here is an idea for you:

Why don't you just do the code that we mentioned, add Steve's line (it's actually a good way to avoid save questions), and since you'd have restore the original value at the end then just save through programmatic function in C# no matter what. So that even if the user has done any changes you would have saved file...no questions asked ;)

step by step:
1) run like normally
2) add Steve's remark
3) do the trick with the variable change I mentioned bellow
4) do save no matter what at the end of the presentation so that any user changes are saved with the document

code snippet for saving are in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908533/saving-a-powerpoint-file-using-c-sharp) answer very well documented

Remark: Remaining issues with this logic is only when the user does intentional changes and at the end does not want to save the work but this is a case not foreseen above. All the other users will not have to suffer through the "Want to save?" question :)

---

try to save previous state first and then before moving away or closing re-assign that old value back to it ;)

1st do

```
String oldValue = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
```

if you need to store outside the frame, use IO to store on file temporary or pass the variable on an outside function/variable value. Then do your code

```
shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Hello world";
```

and after you finish just do again

```
shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = oldValue;
```

or read the value from where you left it :)

hope it helps

Comment: This does not work: the presentation looks exactly as before, but PPT still wants to save and the user has no idea why.

Comment: have a look again, maybe the update can help at least outline a partial solution ;)

Comment: Finally it looks like I better leave it as is, forwarding the responsibility to the user.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the suggestion @oetoni made, you'll want to set the presentation's .Saved state to True after making each change or before allowing the user to quit the show/presentation.

That way, PowerPoint won't think any changes have been made, so won't offer to save the presentation when the user quits.

```
ActivePresentation.Saved = True
```

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Any changes made by the user will be lost.

Comment: so you want to save user changes but not your change? right

Comment: also....why don't you just do the code that we mentioned, add Steve's line (it's actually a good way to avoid save questions), and since you'd have restore the original value at the end then just save through programmatic function in C# no matter what. So that even if the user has done any changes you would have saved file...no questions asked ;)

Comment: @ThomasWeller That depends a great deal on context. It's possible (actually almost certain, given the SlideShow.NextSlide event OP's responding to) that this all runs in slide show view. The user's not going to be making any changes there.

Comment: @oetoni: in that case, I would save the changes made by the user. If the user accidentally or on purpose (to shorten the presentation) deleted 7 slides, they would be gone. I can't do that